# Python csv file to data dictionary multiple keys

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-dictionary

I have a huge csv file with 4 columns.  i'm trying to convert them into a data dictionary.  the first column [0] should be the master key.  when i try to use the dictionary i get a key error.

columns in csv file:Code    Description Category    Detail

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjtrY.png)

```
with open('sample.csv') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
next(reader,None)
code= {}
description= {}
category = {}
detail = {} 
for row in reader:
    code = {row[0]:row[1]}
    description =  {row[0]:row[2]}
    category = {row[0]:row[3]}
    detail = {row[0]:row[4]}
```

output:
{101:'pen',
102:''
103:'book'
104:'paper'
}

{
101:'Writing',
102:'stuff',
103:'school',
104:'office'
}

{
101:'stuff',
102:'stuff',
103:'',
104:''
}

Comment: Have you consider reading it with `pandas` and then transforming it into a `dictionary` [DataFrame to dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)?

Comment: can you add the line of code that triggers the error?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
df.to_dict('records')
```

You would first import it as a `DataFrame` from `Pandas` and then transfrom it into a `dict` with the argument `records`. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) you can see how to `to_dict` works.

Comment: if you think the answer is correct, you can select is the right one. Thanks!